# Development in Windows and Deploy to Ubuntu 16.04 locally using capistrano

Tags: yii, capistrano, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I am finish developing my website in windows. I am using YII framework. Then I am deploying it on the Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. This is physical server I am working on my office. My question can I deploy the project using the capistrano via offline? If yes, how can I do it?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking: no. Capistrano is primarily designed for deploying from a client machine (e.g. your development environment, or a CI environment) to a server via SSH. If you are not in a networked environment (I assume that's what you mean by "offline"), then Capistrano is not an appropriate tool.